# Error with Listview and Cursor adapter

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to use custom adapter and list view. At the moment I'm trying to populate the list view but I'm getting this error, which I've been stuck at for ages. I could really use some guidance if someone has the time to help me out. Thanks a lot.

```
         weatherActivity.xml
            ---------------------
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/weather_day"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="weather day"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/weather_desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/weather_day"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="weather desc"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/weather_wind_dir"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/weather_pic"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="weather_wind_dir"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/weather_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
                </ListView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/weather_pic"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/weather_desc"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/butterfly" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/weather_wind_spd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/weather_wind_dir"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/weather_wind_dir"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/weather_pic"
                    android:text="weather_wind_spd"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            -------

            weather_list_row.xml

            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dip" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/we_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        -------------
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class weatherActivity extends Activity {
        Context context = this;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.weather_activity);

            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContentProvider.WEATHER_TEMPERATURES_URI, null, null, null, null);
            weatherCustomAdapter WCA = new weatherCustomAdapter(this, cursor, false);

            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.weather_list);
            lv.setAdapter(WCA);
        }
    }


    -------

        public class weatherCustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter 
        {
            private LayoutInflater inflater;
            private Context context;
            private ViewHolder holder;

            public static class ViewHolder {
                public TextView desc;
                public TextView title;
            }

            public weatherCustomAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
                super(context, c, autoRequery);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            @Override
            public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("Weather", "We're at bindView!");
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

                int descIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(WeatherTemperatures.MAIN_DESC);
                String desc = cursor.getString(descIndex);

                Log.d("Weather", "We're at bindView1!");
                holder.desc.setText(desc);
            }

            @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                Log.d("Weather", "We're at newView!");
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_list_row, parent, false);

                Log.d("Weather", "We're at newView1!");
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.we_title);
                holder.desc.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 0, 0, 0));
                holder.desc.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); 
                Log.d("Weather", "We're at newView2!");
                view.setTag(holder);
                Log.d("Weather", "We're at newView3!");
                return view;
            }
        }

    ------------

And finally, the error


12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533): Process: com.a_v1, PID: 11533
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at com.a_v1.weatherCustomAdapter.newView(weatherCustomAdapter.java:48)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:252)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14785)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14785)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14785)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14785)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14785)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1985)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1742)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-03 18:47:20.234: E/AndroidRuntime(11533):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: NPE's are often not so difficult to fix. Can you a mark line 48 in your code? btw does `view.findViewById(R.id.we_title);` return a view ?

Comment: did you consider looking what can be null at `com.a_v1.weatherCustomAdapter.newView(weatherCustomAdapter.java:48)`? that would be a good start.

Comment: Line 48 has this:
"View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_list_row, parent, false);"

So technically you both we're right also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initialized `inflater`. You are getting the null pointer exception there. Initialize `inflater` and check if it works.

You can initialize it in `constructor` of the custom adapter

```
public weatherCustomAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
                super(context, c, autoRequery);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                this.context = context;
                inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }
```

Comment: @user2970008 Pleasure to help :)